# go tests cases aren't running in main package

Tags: go

I'm trying to write a simple test to get a better understanding of golang testing but the test case doesn't seem to execute and I'm expecting it to fail.

In my `main.go` I have:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("run")
}

func twoSum(nums []int, target int) []int {
    lookup := make(map[int]int)
    for i, n := range nums {
        c := target - n
        if j, ok := lookup[c]; ok {
            return []int{j, i}
        }
        lookup[n] = i
    }
    return []int{}
}
```

and then in my `main_test.go` I have this:

```
package main

import (
    "reflect"
    "testing"
)

var twoSumsCases = []struct{
    input []int
    target int
    expected []int

} {
    {
         []int{2,7,11,15},
         9,
         []int{0,3},

    },
}

func TesttwoSum(t *testing.T) {

    for _, tc := range twoSumsCases {
        actual := twoSum(tc.input, tc.target)

        eq := reflect.DeepEqual(actual, tc.expected)

        if eq {
            t.Log("expected: ", tc.expected, " actual: ", actual)
        } else {
            t.Error("expected: ", tc.expected, " actual: ", actual)

        }
    }
}
```

then when I run `go test -v`...it tells me that `testing: warning: no tests to run`. I looked at this as an example: https://blog.alexellis.io/golang-writing-unit-tests/...and I think i got everything I need to but not sure why the test isn't executing.

Answer (score 3):

Change the name of the test function to `TestTwoSum`.  This name matches the pattern described in first paragraph of the [testing package documentation](https://godoc.org/testing):

> ... It is intended to be used in concert with the “go test” command, which automates execution of any function of the form
>
> ```
> func TestXxx(*testing.T)
> ```
>
> where Xxx does not start with a lowercase letter. ...

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the test function to this:

```golang
func TestTwoSum(t *testing.T) {
```

Golang tests are pretty case sensitive. The test functions need to be named using Pascal Case starting with "Test" so the `go test` tool can discover it.